# postMessages add submit event listener

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, html5-video, postmessage

I have a simple form in HTML 5 with video API,  I want to play a video when user click submit button

here is demo HTML form input.

HTML 5

```
<form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">E-mail</label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="name" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Submit</button>


                </form>
```

here is js

```
// play a video after the user enter an input email works perfect
        $("input#email").on("change", function () {
            document.getElementById('videoframe').contentWindow.postMessage( "event=fieldchanged&fieldtype=" + "email" + "&value=" + $("input#email").val(), "*");
        });

        //play a video when a user clicks submit button this is not working !!!!!!!
        $("#button").on("click", function () {
            document.getElementById('videoframe').contentWindow.postMessage({
              event: "openSubmit"
            });
            console.log(openSubmit);
        });
```

Everything works perfectly apart from the submit button.

When a user clicks submit button does not play the video.

What do I need to change in order to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

[`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) only accepts a string for the message parameter. You'll need to convert the object to JSON before sending it. Example:

```
document.getElementById('videoframe').contentWindow.postMessage(
  JSON.stringify({
    event: 'openSubmit'
  }),
  '*'
)
```

Comment: hii @samdd did you check??